# Firebase messging crashes the app only in release build

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

My (Flutter) mobile application uses Firebase messaging and it works fine in debug mode, but when I run/build it in the release mode it crashes upon receiving a message from Firebase. I suspect that `onMessage.listen` somehow crashes the app. It happens only on Android devices.

Is there anything that I could've missed during the Firebase project setup or within the Android app configuration?

The following error logs are produced upon receiving a message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(26859): FATAL EXCEPTION: firebase-iid-executor
E/AndroidRuntime(26859): Process: com.company.app, PID: 26859
E/AndroidRuntime(26859): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Illegal class access: 'b.c.a.b.d.a' attempting to access 'b.c.a.b.b.a.c' (declaration of 'b.c.a.b.d.a' appears in base.apk)
E/AndroidRuntime(26859):        at b.c.a.b.d.a.<init>(Unknown Source:169)
E/AndroidRuntime(26859):        at b.c.a.b.d.a.<init>(:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(26859):        at com.google.firebase.messaging.l0.b(:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(26859):        at com.google.firebase.messaging.Y.e(:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(26859):        at com.google.firebase.messaging.m.call(:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(26859):        at b.c.a.b.e.F.run(Unknown Source:4)
E/AndroidRuntime(26859):        at com.google.firebase.messaging.n.execute(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(26859):        at b.c.a.b.e.m.c(Unknown Source:20)
E/AndroidRuntime(26859):        at com.google.firebase.messaging.o.c(:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(26859):        at b.c.a.b.a.a.b(:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(26859):        at b.c.a.b.a.a.a(Unknown Source:21)
E/AndroidRuntime(26859):        at b.c.a.b.a.g.run(Unknown Source:10)
E/AndroidRuntime(26859):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(26859):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(26859):        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.e.b.run(Unknown Source:6)
E/AndroidRuntime(26859):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: Have you change the Sha-1 and download again the json file? Have you get the Sha-1 release version?

Comment: android or ios ?

Comment: @mariofrancois I havent checked the sha 1 option i project setup, should i?

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga its on android

Comment: the last time i face this was on ios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding code below to `/android/app/build.gradle`:

```
...
buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
```

and adding code below to `/android/gradle.properties`:

```
android.enableR8=false
```

Comment: You saved me bro, for me it was only crashing on devices running android 7.